relayjs: How to call two loadQuery functions in serial, with the second query conditional on the first query’s result?
Scenario: I need to call two loadQuery functions in serial. The second query should be executed based on the first query's result.
example
Query 1: Check if the site is in maintenance mode.
Query 2: Fetch auth data.
Current behavior
query 1 and 2 sent in parallel
Expected behavior

Send Query 1.
Based on the response data, send Query 2 or skip Query 2 if the site is in maintenance mode.

  const upgradeQueryRef = loadUpgradeData(environment);  // fetch is site in maintenance mode
  const authQueryRef = loadAuthData(environment); // We need to skip this query if the site is in maintenance mode

  return <SomeOtherProvider>
    <UpdateGuard queryRef={upgradeQueryRef}> // show maintenance if the site is at upgrade time, show children otherwise
      <AuthProvider queryRef={authQueryRef}>
        <RestOfApp/>
      </AuthProvider>
    </UpdateGuard>
  </SomeOtherProvider>

